# Laravel: An unsupported attribute was designated on the PDO object. MSSQL on Ubuntu

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo, sqlsrv

My Ubuntu vagrant Laravel Homestead set up has been configured to connect to MSSQL. Randomly it's starting throwing the following error on every query going to the MSSQL database (on a Windows server).

Any ideas? I can't find much info re:this available on Google.

I restarted PHP and confirmed SQLSRV modules are loaded.

```
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An unsupported attribute was designated on the PDO object. (SQL: select top 10 * from [orders] where [ordertype] = SO order by [orderdate] desc)
```

Comment: For me, I logged what options were being passed in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php on line 69...I had a weird array with numbers, not what I was expecting. I was looking for something with PDO in it. And then I removed the options array from config/database.php that was set for this connection. Then this error went away

Answer (score 3):

[Check this issue report](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/220) `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` is not supported. Also they are reporting problems with `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` so check your connection for these two parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the line "PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES" in the Laravel framework's vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/SqlServerConnector.php file solved the problem.

This was caused by specifying an invalid attribute in the PDO connection settings. This attribute allows the PDO object to automatically convert data types to strings. However, this attribute should not be used with MSSQL databases.

To solve the problem, simply delete this line. Then, restart your Laravel project and you should see that the problem is solved.

Comment: You should not delete anything in your vendor folder. As soon as you install/update it is going to come back

Comment: The solution above worked but as @LeonardChallis said, it will come back and that is a hustle.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone has this problem this is what I had.

PHP version 8.1.23
pdo_sqlsrv version 5.10Beta

Solution that worked form me is I downloaded the latest PDO driver as the time of the posting is 5.11.1+17301. Download from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: This should be marked as the answer because it's the best way to go about solving this problem. Tried it myself after updating various packages on my server and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS users runnning PHP 8.1.23 is latest PDO driver recommended as well. For me 5.11.1+17301 fix this issue https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/download/v5.11.1/Mac-8.1.tar

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue after upgrading to PHP 8 and Laravel 10

Solved by extending the SqlServerConnection and removing the line in the options to stringify fetches

1. create a new class extending the SqlServerConnection

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\SqlServerConnector;
    use PDO;
    
    class CustomSqlServerConnector extends SqlServerConnector
    {
        protected $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_NATURAL,
            //PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
        ];
    }
```

2. Register the new class in the AppServiceProvider register method

```
use App\Services\CustomSqlServerConnector;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Register any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {
            $this->app->bind('db.connector.sqlsrv', CustomSqlServerConnector::class);
        }
```

Comment: Where would I put these files?