# Laravel 10 stopped working with SQL Server Database

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

all of a sudden my laravel app has stopped connecting to SQL server database. No matter what i do, i get the error

`SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An invalid attribute was designated on the PDO object.`

I am able to connect to the database as usual from Microsoft Management Studio and as far as i am concerned nothing has change to the server configuration.

The OS of the server is AlmaLinux 8.8 and it has been running well for the last couple of months that the project started.

```
Route::get('/check_db', function() {
    try {
        DB::connection('sqlsrv')->getPDO();
        echo DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo 'None';
    }
});
```

Adding the above line on the `web.php` and visiting the link i get **None**

**phpinfo()** output
[image]

[image]

PHP version **8.2.9**

PS. It works great with MySQL databases.
PS2. Before you downgrade for duplicate, i need to mention that i already searched everything on stackoverflow and laracasts for this specific error and nothing helped me resovle it.

Any info on what is going wrong?

Comment: "*i need to mention that i already searched everything on stackoverflow*" - Please add the attempts you've already made to the question then...

Comment: Tell us, in detail, everything you tried then, so we can rule it out and don't suggest it again, and we can also check if you applied the resolutions correctly or not. Otherwise it's going to waste a lot of everyone's time. See also [ask], please.

Comment: I tried restarting the services and the server, i tried removing the php packages and re-install them, i removed the odbc drivers and re-installed them, i removed the sql server and i re-installed it, i added the pdo_sqlsrv extension in php.ini but that generated another error not related to the post so i removed it again. The only thing i didn't do is to install a new laravel project and test the connection there and reset the server and start over again.

Comment: Did you see the comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56357081/laravel-an-unsupported-attribute-was-designated-on-the-pdo-object-mssql-on-ubu)?

Comment: @Olivier yes. Passing and empty array to vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php seems to resolve the issue but that cant be the fix to it.. I mean, doing such things to the core of the framework is bad i guess

Comment: @Olivier And i really can't get why this happened this morning out of a sudden while the last couple of months it was working perfectly. No update was done to any part including, system, os, software, laravel project, sql server. Nothing at all

Comment: Did you just upgrade to [PHP SQL 5.11](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/v5.11.0) by chance? _This release requires ODBC Driver 17.4.2 or above. Otherwise, a warning about failing to set an attribute may be suppressed when using an older ODBC driver._

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Definitely not on my own. And i don't believe that it did on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT (2023-09-30)**

The updated version 5.11.1 of (pdo_)sqlsrv has been released in the beginning of September ([github tag](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.11.1)). It contains the pull request mentioned below.

**Previous answer**

The reason is PHP 8.1.22 and 8.2.9 contain a fix for MySQL which uncovered a bug in sqlsrv extension: one of PDO attributes isn't supported in the extension and return an error if set. More information can be found in [this Drupal thread](https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv/issues/3379887).

The error should be fixed by [this merged pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/pull/1468) in next release.

In the meantime you can either:

- downgrade PHP version (and keep it from updating if possible)

or

- temporarily comment out `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` in `sqlsrv` section of `config/database.php` and in `$options` of `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/SqlServerConnector.php` (those changes should be reverted once the fixed sqlsrv extension will be released)