# SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server

Tags: laravel-10, php-8.2

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
PHP: 8.2.4
Laravel: 10.26.2

SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64:

In my Project, I have used multiple databases from different servers one of them being a Microsoft SQL server. I have installed the driver extension in my xampp and also have installed the ODBC driver in my environment. I am using Windows 11 for the local development OS.

the project doesn't have any issues, it works properly.

Can anyone help me to debug and solve the issue?

I have tried installing the extentions from Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server on xampp of php 8.2.4 but still the issue is not solving.

Answer (score 0):

This has relation with this request [Laravel 10 stopped working with SQL Server Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76818310/laravel-10-stopped-working-with-sql-server-database).
I had the same issue ,for me the better solution was downgrade PHP version to 8.1.10